# Adding sub command sqlall to manage.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am a beginner in web development using Django framework. While trying to work on mysql database .

```
python manage.py sqlall appname
```

It gives out the following error

```
Unknown command: '--sqlall'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

How to add a sub command sqlall to manage.py.(i'm not trying to implement it)?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Are you assuming the `sqlall` management command already exists or are you trying to implement it ? It's unclear.

Comment: @Saksow Sorry for the lack of clarity.I'm not trying to implement it.

Comment: @Sayse it changes the model to mysql commands and displays it. But to create the real tables i need syncdb which is also not present in the list of sub commands(checked using python manage.py --help)

Comment: syncdb was replaced with migrate and I still find your question unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sqlall` management command was [removed in Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#removed-features-1-9), along with `syncdb`.

Since Django 1.7, you shouldn't use `syncdb`. Instead, you should create migrations with `makemigrations` and perform the migrations with `migrate`. If you work through the [polls tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/), it explains how to use migrations.

There is now an [`sqlmigrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#sqlmigrate-app-label-migrationname) command that displays the sql commands for a specific migration, without performing the migration.